# Is there a RESTful YouTube API for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rest, youtube

I'm trying to access YouTube from within an iOS app, but the iOS SDK is a bit outdated and the source is abysmal. I'm trying to access the playlist of a particular account and show it as part of an app.

Is there any API or URL endpoint I can use? Do I need to use the SDK, or can I manually craft HTTP requests using Objective-C? (I'm thinking LRResty or something similar.)

**Edit:**

Do I need to have an API key to use the RESTful API? If so, how do I obtain one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep: you want the [Youtube Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html), probably the [playlist feed](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Playlist_feed). Standard HTTP requests will work fine.

Comment: I have configured an application and generated the client secret and client id. In Xcode project, I have added the youTube from GTL service folder. I have then invoked the query using GTLQueryYouTube after the setting the auth using GTMOAuth2Authentication. When I executed the query I got 1001 error code, operation couldn't be completed. 
Does I skipped any steps here? Do we need to set the authentication using GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch before invoking the youtube search list?

Comment: This tutorial I wrote may be helpful: http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with RESTful way with [YouTube Data API](http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html).

[Here](https://github.com/zedoul/ZDYoutubeBrowser/tree/master/ZDYoutubeBrowser) is working example which uses it.

Answer (score 4):

I can give you the example about grabbing youtube channel public activities feed(comments, likes, uploads...) in json forma, without going through login authentication.

1. Login your Google account and go to https://code.google.com/apis/console to create an API project.
2. Select **Create Another Client ID**, select **Installed Application (iOS)**, insert your **redirect URL** and press **Create**.
3. Go to **Service**(left grey panel), and go to the bottom of page to enable **YouTube Data API v3** service.
4. In your Xcode, by using iOS native HTTP protocol, you can just grab the user's channel activities feed by requesting the API:
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?channelId=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=snippet,contentDetails
5. You will get a bunch of data. For video feed, you'll see there's a "videoId". Grab it by using your json-dictionary parser and requesting the API for video:
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=player and you will get the video URL in the json "embedHtml" parameter!
6. Use your native iOS video player to play the video.

API Parameter Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
Video API parameter Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the SDK you are talking about being outdated, but the GDataLibrary for Objective-C can make the connections for you.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

I have been using it to make connections to Google Spreadsheets and its been working pretty well. You can choose to implement select services from the Project so it doesn't weigh your project down at compile time with code that doesn't mean anything to you.

I believe that this library is a pretty looking wrapper for Google Services API's in Objective-C

Here is information on how to set it up for use with your project.

[GData Introduction](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction)

Comment: Yea, was talking about that. It doesn't support ARC at all and won't compile out of the box. Needed way too much tweaking.

Comment: You can still include it in ARC projects, just have to add a couple special compiler directives. all in all, it is pretty sloppy. Took me a little to get it running in my project, just thought it was worth mentioning

Comment: I just followed your link - the info there seems... *better* but as you said, sloppy.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is a new Objective-C api to use google's JSON services: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/